# Insert image into Material-UI AppBar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've been looking for a way to insert a plain image file into the AppBar of Material-UI on the official docs but it seems like the only non-text things you can put in the AppBar are either text icons or SVG icons. Is there a way to display actual images in the AppBar?

Answer (score 3):

There are several options to insert a background image for Material-UI AppBar.

Here is one that I prefer:

1. Import the image:

   ```
   import headerBackground from "../../Assets/headerBackground.png";
   ```
2. Add the image to the stylesheet as follow:

   ```
   header: {
     backgroundImage: `url(${headerBackground})`,
   },
   ```
3. Set the class component:

   ```
   const classes = useStyles();

   return (
    <>
      <AppBar className={classes.header}> ... </AppBar>
   ```

Here is a complete example:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

import headerBackground from "../../Assets/headerBackground.png";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  header: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${headerBackground})`,
  },
}));

export default function Header(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <AppBar className={classes.header}>
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="h6">Scroll to Hide App Bar</Typography>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Material-UI has some components in which there are properties that can be assigned to the image. For example CardMedia - the properties of image. But you can also use the standard tag to insert the image.

```
            <AppBar position="static" color="default" elevation={0} className={classes.appBar}>
                <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                    <img src="/assets/logo.svg" />
                    <nav>
                        <Link variant="button" color="textPrimary" href="#" className={classes.link}>
                            About
                        </Link>
                    </nav>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
```

It works for me.